# if `beforeEach` is placed higher than `describe` block will it still be triggered before each `it`

Tags: jasmine

I have the following piece of code:

```
describe('constructor', function () {
    beforeEach(module('validation'));
    var MaxNodeOccursService;

    beforeEach(inject(['MaxNodeOccurs', function (_MaxNodeOccursService_) {
        MaxNodeOccursService = _MaxNodeOccursService_;
    }]));

    describe('nodeType param', function () {
        it('should throw exception if nodeType is undefined', function () {
            expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, undefined, 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
        });

        it('should throw exception if nodeType is null', function () {
            expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, null, 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
        });

        it('should throw exception if nodeType is an empty string', function () {
            expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, "", 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
        });
    });
```

My question is whether `beforeEach` statements will strill be triggered before each of `it` inside `nodeType param` describe block?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and let us know?

Comment: yeah, I've tested it by putting `console.info('beforeeach is run');` and it's ouputted three times, however I'd like to know for sure this is an expected behavior :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confuse about the execution order of nested testing suite and specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596649/confuse-about-the-execution-order-of-nested-testing-suite-and-specs)

Comment: There's also a nice example spec in the documentation that covers your question: https://jasmine.github.io/2.6/introduction.html#section-Nesting_%3Ccode%3Edescribe%3C/code%3E_Blocks