# confuse about the execution order of nested testing suite and specs

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

All:

I just start the second day study about Jasmine, there is one question about exe order I want to figure out:

This example is from Jasmine 2.0 introduction:
[Jasmine 2.0 Introduction](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

```
describe("Asynchronous specs", function() {
  var value;
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value = 0;
      done();
    }, 1);
  });
  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    value++;
    expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    done();
  });
  describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
    var originalTimeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
      originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });
    it("takes a long time", function(done) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        done();
      }, 9000);
    });
    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
  });
});
```

I tried reading the source, but it only makes me more confused that I even confuse which part I do not understand....ToT

Could anyone just brief explain what does jasmine do when it meet describe beforeEach and it, and how it runs t?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`describe` is like a "test-scope" and it's used to determine on which `it`s beforeAll, afterAll, beforeEach and afterEach has to execute, it can also be used simply to categorize your tests because it's a bit like a "chapter", with a title.

The first `beforeEach` is executed before every `it` in the first `describe` (and the `describe` children).

The first `it` could be written without the done parameter since it contains only synchronous operations.

Then `beforeEach` in the "child" `describe` is executed before each test case inside, then the `it` inside, and finally the `afterEach`, is only executed after each `it` inside the child `describe`.

To sum up, In your exemple the functions are executed in this order :

```
beforeEach1 > it1 > beforeEach1 > beforeEach2 > it2 > afterEach
```

When you pass the done parameter, jasmine "waits" it's execution to proceed to the next test case (`it`). As you can see in the last case, jasmine has to wait 9000ms to execute `done()`: by default, jasmine timeouts after 5000ms, that's why we change it to 10000.

I hope it was clear, if it wasn't enough, feel free to ask for details :)

Comment: Thanks. I get more clear now, one question about the "test-scope": Can the inner test scope inside the inner describe access the variable defined in the outside describe?

Comment: Yes it can, they're just nested functions, so they work the same way

Comment: Thanks, one thing I can not figure out here is: I set a break point inside it function block(at  value++), but it never get called, I wonder why? The error I got from the console is "Spec 'Asynchronous specs long asynchronous specs takes a long time' has no expectations."

Comment: @Kuan You get this error because Jasmine expected `done`to be executed. I never tried to set breakpoints in my test cases so ... I'm afraid I can't help you on this :(

Comment: Thanks, I figure that out. It turns out that each it block need a expect line, if that missing, this error generated.